# Prove there is a $B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ for a given $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, $rank(A)=1$ that $B^*=A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove there is a $B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ for a given $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, $rank(A)=1$ that
>   $B^*=A$.

Here $B^*$ denotes the adjugate matrix of $B$.
I tried with some specific $\mathbb{F}$ and $A$ but have no idea about the general cases.
Here I konw $A=PQ$ for a row vector $Q$ and a column vector $P$ and $rank(B)=n-1$.But I can't move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $P^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(B)P=\operatorname{adj}(P^{-1}BP)$ for any invertible matrix $P$. Therefore, by a change of basis, we may assume that $A$ is already in Jordan normal form, i.e. $A=X\oplus 0_{(n-2)\times(n-2)}$, where
$$
X=\pmatrix{a&0\\ 0&0} \text{ or } \pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}
$$
for some $a\ne0$. In either case, it is not hard to find a $2\times2$ matrix $Y$ such that $X=\operatorname{adj}(Y)$. It follows that $A=\operatorname{adj}(B)$ when $B=Y\oplus I_{n-2}$.